# Regex: Match dot and dash in a 5 digit number

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use a Regex to match only dot and dash from a number that matches in this format: 
`00.000-0`

I'd use a two step way: first checking if the number is in this format `00.000-0` and then matching only the dot and dash, which I'd use a regex pattern like `[^\d]` or `[\.\-]`.

But I'm trying to use in a single step, a Regex pattern that matches the dot after the first two digits and the dash followed by respectively, two digits, dot and three digits.

First, I tried in `regex101.com` with positive lookahead, something like `(?=\d\d)\.(?=\d\d\d)\-`, but it didn't work. Then I tried `(?=\d\d)\.`, so at least I tried to the dot `.` to see if the lookahead was working, but again it didn't work.

I read in `Regular-Expressions.info` and, apparently, the lookahead format I tried was correct.

Is there something else I can do, it matches the dot and dash, only for this format: `00.000-0`?

Answer (score 2):

You might capture the dot and the dash in a capturing group `()`.

From the start of the string `^` match 2 digits `[0-9]{2}`, then capture `(\.)`the dot in capturing group 1, match 3 digits `[0-9]{3}` and capture the dash `(-)` in capturing group 2 and finally match a digit `[0-9]` at the end of the line `$`

[`^[0-9]{2}(\.)[0-9]{3}(-)[0-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/gr3o7P/1)

If your engine supports lookbehinds, an option to match only the dot and the dash could be to match a dot or a hyphen if on the left side and on the right side is the pattern that you would expect.

[`(?<=^\d{2})\.(?=\d{3}-\d$)|(?<=^\d{2}\.\d{3})-(?=\d$)`](https://regex101.com/r/6TZ1CM/1)

Comment: Thanks man, but unfortunately, I using VBA (VBScript Regex), and lookbehinds doesn't work, and the first code doesn't work as expected. I did a two step: using a Regex to check if the data is correct and then remove the dot and dash